# Where is London Chess Classic Pool B's webpage?

Tags: tournament, famous-events

I don't now if here is a right place to ask this question. I think [London Chess Classic](http://www.londonchessclassic.com/gct/gct_schedule.htm) has at least two different pools but I find only one of the pools in their website, is there any page which shows standings and games in the other pool(s)? Or it has only one pool? The main pool (or the only one) is the pool of super grandmasters. I'm also interested to watch weaker pool games and events. I know I can access the games from other websites like chessgames etc but it's strange if they do not associate any page to the other pool (or it's strange if there is no other pool then what is [this](http://chess-results.com/tnr197807.aspx)?)

Answer (score 1):

**Here's how you can find the tournament results:**

*Link* = [Chess Results page](http://chess-results.com/tnr197807.aspx?lan=-1)

Use *ctrl + F* to locate **Tournament selection**

You'll then notice all the sections:

- Super Rapidplay
- FIDE Open
- Weekend Open
- Weekend U2000
- Weekend U1800
- Weekend U120
- Weekday U2000
- Weekday U135
- English Junior Rapidplay

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. This is a link I already provided in the question, it's a third party link and even though I didn't find the live standings / performances etc. Note that all other links there, are also to the same site (chess-results) not to the london chess website and all of them lack what I mentioned before.

Comment: But this is also the link provided by the organisers and it does indeed contain all the information. You can find the standings under "Ranking crosstable after Round 6" and once there you can look at the performances by clicking on the players names.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster, good point, you can provide this as an answer adding the link to the main site where the organizer refers to the chess-results website.